# Could I pick up a human with a strong enough magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, biophysics, levitation

Could I pick up a human with a strong enough magnet?

Humans contain magnetic materials, such as iron.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1vyB-O5i6E :)

Comment: I think diamagnetism of water would counter the ferromagnetism of iron.

Comment: Probably, considering the amount of water compared to iron.

Comment: Related: [How strong of magnetic field would noticibly attract a person?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q15747/), [Is it possible to kill a human with a powerful magnet?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119999/)

Answer (score 0):

(Others can correct me if I'm wrong, but...)

I think the answer is **no**.  Not even theoretically. Humans are basically diamagnetic, because they are mostly water.

Therefore, if you got a large enough magnet, you could repel (or levitate) a person with it, but you could not possibly attract a person with it.

Look up the Ignobel Prize for levitating a frog. Levitating a person would be basically the same thing, you would "just" need much more powerful magnets.

Comment: so which is the correct answer here, experts ?

Comment: Have you seen the videos of magnetically levitated frogs? They are worth watching.